# How to set background color for a table in primefaces

Tags: primefaces

How to set background color for a table in primefaces?

Comment: `DataTable`? If so, use the style attribute like this: `style="background-color: blue;"` or you can use the `styleClass` attribute and reference a class from your CSS file.
Also see http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/home.jsf for demos of the widgets and their behaviour like styling as well...

Answer (score 0):

To declare it into your p:datatable tag, use the following:

```
<p:dataTable ... style="background-color: red" />
```

If you already have a css class for your datatable, just put the property "background-color" into the class

`<p:dataTable ... styleClass="dtTableClass" />`

yourCSSClass.css:

```
 .dtTableClasse {
 background-color: red;
 }
```

If it's not working, try to use the property !important after the attribute, BUT DON'T KEEP IT... try to understand how the styles behave in different classes (http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/cascade.html)